# How to selectively output ttest results with P value less than 0.05 in SPSS and STATA

Tags: statistics, spss

Does anybody know how to output/report the paired ttest results only (selectively) with Sig. <0.05, using SPSS or STATA syntax?

Comment: Can you expand your question a little bit and tell us what you're trying to do?  Running a lot of t-tests and then pulling out only those with p-values < 0.05 usually isn't good statistics...

Comment: Yes, I wanted to display only the results with P <0.05.  Data had 1121 variables in 59 column groups and 5 rows (observations). We considered the paired ttest for parametric endpoint and cont. variables. Thanks, folks